# Selenium Commands not detecting even though added all the dependencies in Maven Project

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Selenium commands not detecting

[image]

I am using below versions:

- Eclipse - Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)
- Java - jdk 17
- selenium dependencies in Maven - 4.9.0

Tried changing the Selenium versions and add library to Java 17, imported selenium packages:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
```

Not sure what is missing? is there any eclipse versions which not support latest selenium Jars
I am new to this and interested to practice the Selenium programs